# The page cannot be scrolled and is only as large as the background image

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have a page and there is a background image, but I would like to make the page larger so that I can continue working with a white, empty background after the background image.
Code HTML:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Hittedal';
    /*src: url(Hittedal.ttf) format('truetype');*/
}



body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.header {
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 20px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}

.logo {
    font-size: 35px;
    /*font-family: "Hittedal" ;*/
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar a {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif ;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.navbar a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    transition: .3s;
}
.navbar a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}

.text1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 325px;
    bottom: ;
    left: 150px;
    right: ;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128, .3);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 19px;
}
.box{
    position: fixed;
    top: px;
    bottom: ;
    left: ;
    right: ;
    width: 1920px;
    height: ;
    background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Pizza&Pasta Lina</a>

  <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="">Home</a>
      <a href="">Speisekarte</a>
      <a href="">Bilder</a>
      <a href="">Kontakt</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="box">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I would like to have a scrollable page that continues after the first background image with a blank white background.

Comment: Do you have a background at all? Because for me it is `background: url('Haupthintergrund.jpg');`.

Comment: Isn't that a background

Comment: I meant, if the background does show? Because the quotes `''` are missing, 

Comment: The background works but when I try to move text or something out of the field of view so that the page expands and is scrollable, the texts disappear and you can't scroll either.

Comment: if you put your image as a background in the body it will take the whole body size. You may need to specify background-size

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/oyb4w27q/5/ ?

Comment: thanks it works perfectly i don't understand it one hundred percent but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your codes, your problem comes from where you were added your background! I mean you added background in **body** which leads to have it full page and doesn't let you to have empty white space.
For this purpose **you can define a div element and set the background into it** and when it finishes, you can have your white and empty space.

Sample code:

```
<div class="content-with-background"></div>
<div class="box">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

and then add your image background to the "content-with-background" CSS class.

Good Luck!